# mysql client console broken for some utf-8 encoded characters

Tags: console, character-encoding, mysql

I can write my language specific characters into mysql console, but when backspacing or moving right and left on the line, it gets messed up, and I have to ctrl + c because the console can't be used at all then. Otherwise the character set is properly set up. My platform (linux) charset is set to UTF-8....this is just a bug I can't get information about. I hope somebody has dealt with this issue and can tell me how to fix it.

mysql 5.0.84

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%';
+--------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name            | Value  |
+--------------------------+--------+
| character_set_client     | utf8   |
| character_set_connection | utf8   |
| character_set_database   | utf8   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results    | utf8   |
| character_set_server     | utf8   |
| character_set_system     | utf8   |
+--------------------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```